# git count files in the staged index

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out how to easily count the files in my uncommitted index.

I've tried:

```
git status | grep '#' | wc -l
```

but there are a few lines that start with `#` that don't represent changed files. Anyone got anything better? Figured there had to be a flag for `git status` to do this.

Even tools like GitX don't easily allow you to select the staged files/directories and see how many of them there are.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you want something a script can use:

`git diff --cached --numstat | wc -l`

If you want something human readable:

`git diff --cached --stat`

Comment: Why the --cached flag?

Comment: @Humdinger The question was about uncommitted files in the index, which is what `--cached` shows. Without `--cached`, it would show files that are changed in the working directory but not the index (i.e. unstaged files).

Comment: Just to note, if the amount of changes is large, you have to scroll down a long way in the human readable way. I added the `| tail -n1` that @fwiw added, but sadly his didn't do indexed files as asked by the OP.

Answer (score 43):

This worked for me:

`git status | grep 'modified:' | wc -l`

it returns a number

Comment: And that number is "1"

Comment: ...or deleted files.

Answer (score 32):

For what it's worth, I prefer:

```
git diff --stat | tail -n1
```

Outputs something like:

```
10 files changed, 74 insertions(+), 123 deletions(-)
```

Comment: btw, you can use [`--shortstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---shortstat) in order to "*Output only the last line of the --stat format containing total number of modified files, as well as number of added and deleted lines.*" (instead of `stat` + `tail`)

Answer (score 20):

Try [`git status -s`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status--s):

```
git status -s | egrep "^M" | wc -l
```

`M` directly after start-of-line (`^`) indicates a staged file. `^ M`, with a space, would be an unstaged but changed file.

Comment: Thanks, that returned 0 but `git status -s | egrep "^M " | wc -l` worked. I think the space needs to be on the other side of the "M" in the regex.

Comment: Ah and to include other types of changes (added, renamed, created, deleted): `git status -s | egrep -c "^[MARCD]"`

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has so few votes. This one is most easily adaptable to report all possible states.

Comment: Simpliest and best approach for me. You should also consider adding a `| -grep -v '^??'` to filter the unstaged files

Answer (score 9):

This has lots of answers... but the best command imo (it doesn't require any piping and is a pure native git command) is just the following. Note that this counts deleted, modified, and added files:

```sh
git diff --cached --shortstat
```

The output is only one line:

```
X files changed, Y insertions(+), Z deletions(-)
```

If no changes have been made, it prints nothing (not even a new empty line).

It's also obvious how to get the same result for unstaged changes (just omit the `--cached` flag):

```sh
git diff --shortstat
```

Answer (score 2):

Below should cover for all cases (new, modified, deleted and even untracked), it returns a number.

```
(git status -s |select-string -Pattern "^\s*[A|\?|D|M]" -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a PowerShell solution:

```
(git diff --cached --numstat | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was not available 9 years ago, but as of 2019, `ls-files` is much faster than `diff --stat`:

```
git ls-files --cached | wc -l
```

Edit: I upvoted @derpedy-doo's answer which is better.

Comment: With zero uncommitted changes (according to `git status`) this says I've changed thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

```
git --no-pager diff --shortstat <master>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?