# How to count unstaged files in git?

Tags: windows, git

I've found [a way to count the **staged** files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162492/1525840). However, I'd like to get a count of the exact opposite, i.e. to learn how many files that are in the red.

When I execute *git status*, I see I deleted a bunch of file. However, I'd like to know how many that is. Then, I will go *git reset* in the same branch and check the number of tracked files (now in green, up to date). That way, I can learn how many junky files I had in my repo that wasn't tracked.

Surprisingly, googling *how to count unstaged files* gave no hits, so I wonder if I'm perhaps missing something very trivial at this ungodly early hour.

Comment: is it what you are looking for ? 
`git status -s -uno | wc -l`

Comment: Consider using `git ls-files` with various flags, such as `-m` (modified) or `-o` ("others" = untracked). Note that `-o` does not respect `.gitignore` unless you add `-x`, though. Piping these through `wc -l`, as @Prakash suggests, gets you the counts you desire.

Comment: @Prakash Not sure. It seems that *wc* doesn't exist as a command in PowerShell and running only *git status -s -uno* brings nothing to the screen. I understand that *-s* is short for *-short* and *-uno* is there for [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334975/what-is-git-status-uno-in-git) (although it's not mention in the help). Only *git status* produces a list of results, though. What am I missing?

Comment: @torek I think I can do with *git ls-files -x -o* (although setting up the pattern manually, not referring to -gitignore is less pleasant. Still, it strikes me as odd that there's so little automagic stuff for this specific purpose. Also, I don't seem to get the *wc* working. Didn't see anything in git's docs about it, neither. What do I miss?

Comment: Do you want to find the number of files which are tracked and have been deleted, or the number of untracked files?

Comment: `wc` is a standard Unix tool. We're assuming you have standard Unix tools. :-) I mentioned the need for `-x` in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in git you can use the command

```
git status -s -uno | wc -l
```

if you want to go with powershell use below code

```
git status -s -uno | Measure-Object -Line
```

please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Sorry for the late get-back. I forgot this question and was reminded by someone else answering it. Your reply is better. For +1, I'd like the flags to be explicitly spelled out, though. It's so cryptic with those `git someCommand -kjshdfkjds`. I prefer the pedagogic `git commit --message "Load of new bugs"`.

Comment: When I run this command, the count looks to me to include both unstaged and staged files.

Answer (score 4):

The exact command to do this would be:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | wc -l
```

The `--others` option will include the untracked files. `--exclude-standard` option will ignore the files ignored by `.gitignore`

Piping to `wc -l` will return a count of the output of `ls-files`